# SQL query with python variable

Tags: python, sql, variables

I'm trying to execute an sql query with a python variable named var1

```
sqlUpdate = ("UPDATE highscore SET score = %s WHERE brugerID=4")
        mycursor.execute(sqlUpdate, var1)
```

But I get this error

```
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s WHERE brugerID=4' at line 1
```

I would appreciate any help I could get

Comment: What library are you using for the execute method? Do you think that %s is replaced with the value of var1?

Comment: Is *var1* iterable? If not, try *mycursor.execute(sqlUpdate, [var1])*

Comment: since it's in python, I think they could also use .format() on the string as well